# Java 6 u13 quickstart service (jqs)

Tags: windows-xp, java

As some may be aware of, java innitialy enables the java quickstart service on windows xp x86 machines.

It's easily disabled by unchecking it in the java control panel.
The problem however is that we need to deploy java 6 u16 to all clients in our organisation, and we don't want this service.

Does anyone know of a way to remove it other than using the java control panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip it in the install process with [**ORCA MSI Editor**](http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html).

When installing java, on the last page where it says **Finish**, navigate to your `Application Data\Sun\Java` folder and find the JRE folder inside before clicking Finish. You will see an MSI and .CAB file. You will need both, so copy them to another folder. Now, open the MSI with ORCA, and edit the `InstallExecuteSequence` table. Add this one-liner:

```
UninstallJQS    NOT Installed    3184
```

that should uninstall the service right after it's installed. When deploying Java, make sure the MSI and Cabinet file are in the same directory. I know the process isn't exactly what you'd call "convenient", but when deploying on tens or hundreds or even thousands of computers, this is a life saver. You may want to bookmark [**App Deploy**](http://www.appdeploy.com/index.asp), this site is a must know for all administrators, it's a great resource.

Comment: Thanks, can't belive I didn't think of that! Never the less, much appreciated :)

Comment: you may want to check the site I added, lots of experts there that work in the administration field explain how they deploy certain applications.